# How can people submit a form but not to read the content of the list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, infopath

Using a list I have created a form in info path and I published into a separate page. now if I want users to submit the form I need to give them read and write to the specific site. But I wanted to make sure the content of the list should be confidential cannot able to view by anyone.

My questions:

1. how to restrict users not to view the content of the list?
2. how to restrict users can't able to view the list understand site contents?

Answer (score 1):

If the user whom submits the list item can also see / edit their own list item you can change that in List Settings > Advanced Settings > Item-level Permissions (or using powershell for document libraries).  The user will not be able to see others items & will be able to use the form.

You could also copy the item via workflow to another more secure list & delete the original.

Alternatives to InfoPath (deprecated) are to use SharePoint Apps (Add-Ins) however that's a bit of a heavy solution that would require you build your own app (form+code etc.).  Using this model you can lock down the list & allow edits through app only privileges.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/app-only-elevated-privileges-sharepoint-add-in

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Then in that case if the manager wants to approves it then other person can view that item on the list. It's like more or like submission tool once it's submitted email will trigger and based on the email the approved need to view it n do the approval. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the above solution but I used a workaround, where the user submits the form via e-mail to the owner of the library. They quality control the form and add any comments needed to the said form before they submit it to the library.

The person submitting the form does not have access to the library. It works for the requirements that we had but understand this is not suitable for all.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a suffix '?Source=gotopage.aspx' to the link to the form:

http://www.sharepoint.com/mysite/SitePages/formpage.aspx?Source=success.aspx

It can only be a filename if it is in the same directory as the form, otherwise use full url.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and couldn't find what I was looking for so I created a Permission Level and named it *Submit*. Then added the **Permissions** to the List and Site:

1. List: Add Items, View Items, Open Items, View Applications, and View Pages.
2. Site: Browse User Information, Use Remote Interface, Use Client Integration Features, and Open.

Go to the list's settings and chose 'Permissions for this List'. Select the group that you to associate the Permission Level (usually Visitors) to, then 'Edit User Permissions' and add *Submit* to the group. It's been working so far.

Answer (score 0):

Could add a workflow to trigger on new or updated items. Just one command to change permissions on the item to either no one, or whomever is supposed to see it, and remove permissions from everyone else. That way the documents are all in the same library you started the form in and only the desired people can see it.